# Material theme api level 14

Tags: android, material-design

I  am building an app and i  want to use material theme in my app with api level 14 can anyone help me out. I tried it but it was wit api level 21. I want it with api level 14.

Answer (score 0):

[**v7 Support Libraries**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7) - There are several libraries designed to be used with **Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher**. These libraries provide specific feature sets and can be included in your application independently from each other

you have to use **v7 appcompat library** - This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design pattern. This library includes support for [material design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) user interface implementations.